# How does auto handicap in Super Smash Bros Brawl work?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

I've never used it but before I do...I'd like to be informed of how it works, or at least in what increments it increases your percentage. Thx :)
I've used the manual handicapping, does it increase in the same increments as those, and if so by what factors?

Comment: why not just use it and find out ...?

Comment: I have a short attention span, if I turned it on and won a lot, then it'd be sudden death every match and I still wouldn't notice XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://supersmashbros.fandom.com/wiki/Handicap) wiki should answer your question. At the very end, talking about Brawl:

> When the Handicap is set to AUTO, all players will start with 0%. Every time a player wins, they gain 20% handicap. Every other player will lose 10% handicap, assuming that they have 10+% handicap.

Comment: This does answer the question, though might not be clear to people who don't play smash bros. When it says "All players start at 0%" it is talking about damage percentage. So a player with 20% handicap will spawn (and respawn after losing a stock) with 20% damage percentage.